# Why does my Rust Rocket project recompile dependencies every time I make a change?

Tags: rust, build, compilation, rocket

I am building a Rocket-based web server in Rust following [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2020/06/03/build-smart-bookmarking-tool-rust-rocket/) I found that every time I make a small build and rerun `cargo run`, it build the Rocket dependencies again. I thought Rust had incremental compilation, and should not normally require a recompilation of dependencies. The code is [here](https://github.com/samsonjj/samson-lol/tree/ab19cc44755625430e1cf4b6a0c49797e342ac27).

OS:
Ubuntu 22 on a home server

Making a simple change like adding a println!(...), and then running `cargo run` results in the following:

this line for a few seconds

```
    Blocking waiting for file lock on build directory
```

```
   Compiling version_check v0.9.4
   Compiling libc v0.2.137
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling autocfg v1.1.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.47
   Compiling unicode-ident v1.0.5
   Compiling quote v1.0.21
   Compiling syn v1.0.103
   Compiling typenum v1.15.0
   Compiling pin-project-lite v0.2.9
   Compiling memchr v2.5.0
   Compiling futures-channel v0.3.25
   Compiling futures-core v0.3.25
   Compiling subtle v2.4.1
   Compiling bytes v1.2.1
   Compiling pin-utils v0.1.0
   Compiling log v0.4.17
   Compiling serde_derive v1.0.147
   Compiling itoa v1.0.4
   Compiling serde v1.0.147
   Compiling yansi v0.5.1
   Compiling once_cell v1.16.0
   Compiling cpufeatures v0.2.5
   Compiling fnv v1.0.7
   Compiling futures-task v0.3.25
   Compiling httparse v1.8.0
   Compiling opaque-debug v0.3.0
   Compiling tracing-core v0.1.30
   Compiling futures-util v0.3.25
   Compiling http v0.2.8
   Compiling try-lock v0.2.3
   Compiling hashbrown v0.12.3
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.6
   Compiling proc-macro2-diagnostics v0.9.1
   Compiling slab v0.4.7
   Compiling tokio v1.21.2
   Compiling ppv-lite86 v0.2.17
   Compiling time-core v0.1.0
   Compiling tracing v0.1.37
   Compiling futures-sink v0.3.25
   Compiling time-macros v0.2.6
   Compiling indexmap v1.9.1
   Compiling cookie v0.16.1
   Compiling inlinable_string v0.1.15
   Compiling tower-service v0.3.2
   Compiling smallvec v1.10.0
   Compiling httpdate v1.0.2
   Compiling ref-cast v1.0.13
   Compiling uncased v0.9.7
   Compiling base64 v0.13.1
   Compiling percent-encoding v2.2.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling stable-pattern v0.1.0
   Compiling getrandom v0.2.8
   Compiling socket2 v0.4.7
   Compiling mio v0.8.5
   Compiling signal-hook-registry v1.4.0
   Compiling num_cpus v1.14.0
   Compiling rand_core v0.6.4
   Compiling want v0.3.0
   Compiling http-body v0.4.5
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.9
   Compiling state v0.5.3
   Compiling futures-io v0.3.25
   Compiling either v1.8.0
   Compiling encoding_rs v0.8.31
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.4
   Compiling rand_chacha v0.3.1
   Compiling atomic v0.5.1
   Compiling multer v2.0.4
   Compiling figment v0.10.8
   Compiling async-trait v0.1.58
   Compiling rocket v0.5.0-rc.2
   Compiling rand v0.8.5
   Compiling unicode-xid v0.2.4
   Compiling glob v0.3.0
   Compiling crypto-common v0.1.6
   Compiling inout v0.1.3
   Compiling block-buffer v0.10.3
   Compiling tempfile v3.3.0
   Compiling parking_lot v0.12.1
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling universal-hash v0.5.0
   Compiling aead v0.5.1
   Compiling cipher v0.4.3
   Compiling digest v0.10.6
   Compiling time v0.3.17
   Compiling polyval v0.6.0
   Compiling ghash v0.5.0
   Compiling aes v0.8.2
   Compiling ctr v0.9.2
   Compiling hmac v0.12.1
   Compiling sha2 v0.10.6
   Compiling hkdf v0.12.3
   Compiling futures v0.3.25
   Compiling aes-gcm v0.10.1
   Compiling hyper v0.14.23
   Compiling devise_core v0.3.1
   Compiling tokio-macros v1.8.0
   Compiling pear_codegen v0.2.3
   Compiling ref-cast-impl v1.0.13
   Compiling devise_codegen v0.3.1
   Compiling async-stream-impl v0.3.3
   Compiling async-stream v0.3.3
   Compiling devise v0.3.1
   Compiling pear v0.2.3
   Compiling rocket_http v0.5.0-rc.2
   Compiling rocket_codegen v0.5.0-rc.2
   Compiling tokio-util v0.7.4
   Compiling tokio-stream v0.1.11
   Compiling toml v0.5.9
   Compiling ubyte v0.10.3
   Compiling h2 v0.3.15
   Compiling samson-lol v0.1.0 (/home/<me>/dev/samson-lol)
```

but really I expect just the simple output

```
   Compiling samson-lol v0.1.0 (/home/<me>/dev/samson-lol)
```

Answer (score 1):

So I was using nightly rust, `cargo --version` prints out

```
cargo 1.67.0-nightly (16b097879 2022-11-14)
```

Switching back to stable via `rustup default stable` solved the issue.

Comment: Actually you were probably using _both_ versions: the stable version in your IDE and the nightly version for `cargo run`. So each time you made a change, your IDE would recompile with stable, then `cargo run` would need to recompile everything with nightly since the available compiled code was for a different version.